# htaccess to Redirect users to mobile site BUT still allow requests from the mobile site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mobile, redirect

I use the following snippet in my htaccess:

```
# redirect phones/tablets to mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mobile\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mobile.website.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

However, inside my mobile app, I make AJAX requests to `www.website.com/mobile`, and they are all failing. How can I send these AJAX requests and still redirect them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !mobile\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mobile.website.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

It will unblock the /mobile and your ajax requests will work.